# Hadoop setup and configuration

Tags: hadoop

C:\hadoop-2.3.0\bin>hadoop
The system cannot find the path specified.
Error: JAVA_HOME is incorrectly set.
       Please update C:\hadoop-2.3.0\conf\hadoop-env.c
Usage: hadoop [--config confdir] COMMAND

Facing above error in Hadoop configuration. Can anyone please help to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If this is for learning purpose to setup hadoop on windows you will find enough blog [link](https://github.com/MuhammadBilalYar/Hadoop-On-Window/wiki/Step-by-step-Hadoop-2.8.0-installation-on-Window-10)

If your primary objective is to learn Hadoop then i will suggest you to download VMware Player and setup hadoop on ubantu or you can download CDH version from cloudera website to start your learning.